# How to use await expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-3.5

Couldn't figure out how to use await from python 3.5-rc2

```
>>> async def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> await foo()
  File "<ipython-input-10-a18cb57f9337>", line 1
    await foo()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> c = foo()
>>> await c
  File "<ipython-input-12-cfb6bb0723be>", line 1
    await c
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.5.0rc2 (default, Aug 26 2015, 21:54:21) \n[GCC 5.2.0]'
>>> del c
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
>>>
```

Comment: I checked [PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#examples-of-await-expressions) and that seems like it should be valid. Could they have changed it or something?

Comment: Maybe it has to be part of [some larger construct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax)?

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-def

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#await), `await` can only be used inside a coroutine function. So the correct syntax for using it should be

```
async def foo():
    pass

async def bar():
    await foo()
```

Comment: If I have to use the coroutine, I have to create a function and then await on it to get the value?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a function, as long as it is an awaitable object (i.e. native and generator-based coroutine or an object with the magic method `__await__`) @balki

Answer (score 7):

Just like in C#, `await` can only be used in an `async` method (function).